# Print kotlinx datetime with timezone

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime

Im creating an Instant by calling kotlinx.datetime `Clock.System.now()`.

I would like to convert it to a String with added timezone.

So it would look like this `2023-01-06T00:00:00.000+01:00`. (ISO-8601)

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an extension function for this and used a formatter.

```
// 2023-04-17T10:16:45.205+02:00
fun Instant.formatTimestampWithZoneOffset(): String =
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"))
        .format(this.toJavaInstant())
```

Answer (score -1):

Using:

static val RFC_1123_DATE_TIME: DateTimeFormatter!

Example:

// create with same format as RFC_1123_DATE_TIME

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()

    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .parseLenient()
    .optionalStart()
    .appendText(DAY_OF_WEEK, dow)
    .appendLiteral(", ")
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendText(MONTH_OF_YEAR, moy)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4)  // 2 digit year not handled
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    // difference from RFC_1123_DATE_TIME: optional offset OR zone ID
    .optionalStart()
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "GMT")
    // use the same resolver style and chronology
    .toFormatter().withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART).withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

The result is:

```
With this formatter, I can parse the inputs:
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("Mon, 21 Aug 2017 15:00:00 EST")));
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("Sun, 20 Aug 2017 00:30:00 UT")));
```